# Transfer multiple TextViews to "compose email" IF corresponding checkboxes are checked in Java/Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, checkbox, onclick

EDIT: I have been unable to comment, even though this is my own question. So I am going to post my comments here. I checked my CheckBoxes and their IDs several times and everything seems fine. Tried renaming and anything I could think of. Still no resolution. Any ideas what else could be causing that error?

ORIGINAL POST:
I have been trying to figure this out for hours at this point and would love some help. I am very new at coding - taking an online class and this is my final project.

I have created 7 XML layouts for this activity. I am switching from layout 1 to 2, etc., using buttons, and that part works. I have added multiple checkboxes in 5 of the XML layouts. When the Submit button is clicked, the text above each of the checked checkboxes is supposed to be poppulated to the "compose email" of an email app. When I try to run it, it works until I press the last button - that's when the app crashes.

```
package com.example.android.theultimatebakingsodaguide;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void healthPage(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.

        ScrollView scrollHealthPage = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_health_page);
        setContentView(R.layout.health_page);

    }

    public void beautyPage(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.

        ScrollView scrollBeautyPage = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_beauty_page);
        setContentView(R.layout.beauty_page);

    }

    public void personalCarePage(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.

        ScrollView scrollPersonalCarePage = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_personal_care_page);
        setContentView(R.layout.personal_care_page);

    }
    public void cleaningPage(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.

        ScrollView scrollCleaningPage = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_cleaning_page);
        setContentView(R.layout.cleaning_page);

    }
    public void deodorizingPage(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.

        ScrollView scrollDeodorizingPage = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_deodorizing_page);
        setContentView(R.layout.deodorizing_page);

    }
    public void favoritesPage(View view) {

        LinearLayout scrollDeodorizingPage = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.favorites_linear);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorite_tips);

    }

    public void emailFavorites(View view) {
        CheckBox healthFav01 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.health_fav_01);
        boolean pickHealthFav01 = healthFav01.isChecked();

        CheckBox healthFav02 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.health_fav_02);
        boolean pickHealthFav02 = healthFav02.isChecked();


        EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_email);
        String userEmail = emailText.getText().toString();

        String tipSummary = favoriteTipsSummary(pickHealthFav01, pickHealthFav02);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your favorite baking soda tips");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The baking soda tips you selected are here!" + tipSummary);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, userEmail);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


    private String favoriteTipsSummary(boolean pickHealthFav01, boolean pickHealthFav02) {
        String tipSummary = "We hope those are helpful!";
        TextView healthTip01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.health_tip_01);
        String sHealthTip01 = healthTip01.getText().toString();
        if (pickHealthFav01) {tipSummary += sHealthTip01;}
        TextView healthTip02 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.health_tip_02);
        String sHealthTip02 = healthTip02.getText().toString();
        if (pickHealthFav02) {tipSummary += sHealthTip02;}
        return tipSummary;
    }

}
```

I have assigned IDs to each checkbox and to its corresponding text view.
I tried writing the code only for the first two checkboxes to test if it works. When I figure it out, I'll do the same for the rest (I have many). I know this is too complicated for my current level, but I am trying to challenge myself and learn by doing. Please, help! Thanks in advance!

P.S. Here are the error messages I am getting (Please, scroll to the right). I can't find my errors in the code.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.theultimatebakingsodaguide, PID: 23472
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
 at com.example.android.theultimatebakingsodaguide.MainActivity.emailFavorites(MainActivity.java:76)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: The error shows -- **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference at com.example.android.theultimatebakingsodaguide.MainActivity.emailFavorites(MainActivity.java:76)** -- Try to check your xml again. It's saying that the ***CheckBox healthFav01 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.health_fav_01);*** is null for some reason. Maybe the reference is incorrect or maybe the view itself is missing. Happy hunting. :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null
> ```
>
> object reference
>        at com.example.android.theultimatebakingsodaguide.MainActivity.emailFavorites(MainActivity.java:76)

`boolean pickHealthFav01 = healthFav01.isChecked();` is where is error happens.  Check if the check box is within the activity that you are referring to. Also check if you are referring to correct id.

or try something like,

```
if (healthFav01.isChecked() != null){
//do the assignments
}
```

But its not the best practice. Let me know if you have any issues